# change listview row background on click

Tags: listview, colors, background, row

I need to change background color of a row in a listview when it's clicked by the finger.
Example: I've got as listview with 5/6 rows; I need that with a single click on one row its background color becomes green (selected). With an other click on the selected row the background becames black again.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Please name the target platform if you want an answer ...

Answer (score 3):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;  

        if (convertView == null)
        {   
           convertView.setTag(holder);  
        }       
        else {
                 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }   
        if(position == your selected row position)
        {
          convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        return convertView;

    }
```